# How to pass pm2 env variables into the node repl?

Tags: node.js, environment-variables, pm2

Imagine that I have some pm2 configuration file with some env variables into it:

```
"env"         : {
  "NODE_ENV": "development",
  "MONGO_ENABLED" : true,
  "MONGO_URI": "mongodb://localhost:27017/cindx-dev",
},
```

How can I run the `node` REPL, so all this environment variables will be enabled?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you want to set the variables in code or the command line before running the process...?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess they use this code, if not some other code to load that. 
https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/blob/91786108d71b3fc6c182750c09b494619e28b28a/lib/ProcessContainer.js#L16

```
// Load all env-vars from master.
var pm2_env = JSON.parse(process.env.pm2_env);
for(var k in pm2_env) {
  process.env[k] = pm2_env[k];
}
```

So for you just run something like

```
var obj={
  "NODE_ENV": "development",
  "MONGO_ENABLED" : true,
  "MONGO_URI": "mongodb://localhost:27017/cindx-dev",
};
Object.keys(obj).forEach(k=>process.env[k]=obj[k])
```